# SQL: Execute a query for range of dates but date wise

Tags: oracle, date

I have a query as below

```
select count(*) from schema.tablename where columnname  
Between To_Timestamp ('2017-07-01 00:00:00.000000','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF') And 
To_Timestamp ('2017-07-01 23:59:59.000000','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF') and column_2='D' order by columnname desc;
```

If I have to execute same query to collect the statistics from July 1st to July 17th as day wise then I have to execute the query 17-times.

Is there any way I can iterate the date, so that I can give starting and ending date and query will fetch count of rows day wise. For example as below

```
Date        Number of rows
7/1/2017    3865
7/2/2017    2981
7/3/2017    21391
```

Thank you.

Comment: Oracle errors come from Oracle, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you want:

```
select date(column_created), count(*)
from schema.tablename
group by date(column_created)
order by date(column_created) desc;
```

Oracle errors come from Oracle, not MySQL.  The syntax in Oracle is:

```
select trunc(column_created), count(*)
from schema.tablename
group by trunc(column_created)
order by trunc(column_created) desc;
```

Comment: But wouldnt it give statistics from all dates ? If I want to restrict my search between specific dates ?

Comment: I may have confused you with meaning less naming conventions I have choose for column names, but I have corrected now. Please review my post once again.

Comment: @Ten-Coin . . . You can still add a `where` to get the date range that you want.

Comment: I am getting below error `ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"` while executing.